# Slow Word's startup as it tries to connect to something

Tags: microsoft-word, performance, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2013

Before, Microsoft Word on my PC startup very quickly and smoothly. I think it took less than 2 second to start.

Recently the time to get to a ready screen suddenly increased a lot (~20s). I think it tries to connect to something at startup, but I cannot verify what it is (tried ping, go to the address...). However the line telling that Word is trying to connect to something does not appear all the time:

[image: Word splash screen]

And this is the current add-ins I have:

[image: Add-ins]

Is there someway to inspect and remove this start up problem? 
I know there's an option of:

```
winword.exe /a
```

This one will load Word without any add-in and not allow the program to connect to the internet. Setting up a firewall rule to block Word's ability to connect to the internet was also a suggested "solution" I've read, but those are just workarounds to the problem, not fixing it at the root.

Comment: It appears to me that Word is trying to load something from file share may be a macro or a template. Can you check for this and see if you have any reference of that location ?

http://i.stack.imgur.com/E3KhU.png

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I checked, the Trusted Locations are all local (no location on shared folder), and the option "Allow..." is always unchecked. http://i.imgur.com/tu8wvg1.png

Comment: Have you tried accessing that file share ? See what's in there ? Is there any template added in Word ?

Comment: File > Options > Addins > Manage > Word Addins

Comment: Some add-ins related to MathType. Tried to uncheck but it keeps coming back checked >> http://i.imgur.com/4pIwJBH.png

Comment: Perhaps it would help to run Ccleaner (Cleaner -> Applications -> Office, and Registry -> Scan for issues.  Then check Startup -> Scheduled tasks.  Also, did you go into Programs and Features, and do a Repair of Office?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that the culprit is MathType (or to be exact, its add-ins).
I tried to turn on and off the add-ins one by one. After uninstalling MathType, Word starts in half a second.

Don't know if I need/should keep the items in Active Application Add-ins there, but at least for now I'm happy with the startup speed.

[image]

(Will not re-install MathType soon, anyway for serious documents, I'm going with LaTex.)

---

UPDATE:
After testing with reinstalling and uninstalling MathType again, I'm 100% sure that it is the cause of the long start up time.
The problem is also addressed by Design Science themselves here:
http://www.dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/tsn/TSN75.htm

**For Word 2010-2013:**

- From the File menu choose Options
- Along the left pane of the resulting window click on Add-Ins
- At the bottom of the window, next to "Manage" use the drop-down menu to choose Word Add-ins and click Go
- In the list of currently active templates, uncheck the box next to MathType Commands 6 for Word 201#.dotm.
- To re-activate the add-in follow the steps detailed here but place a check next to MathType Commands 6 for Word 201#.dotm.

Comment: Glad you found it at last :D